# kCLErrorDomain error 5 : CLLocationManager won't let me register more than 10 devices on my iPhone 7

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location

First question asked here so bear with me.

I have a project relying heavily on beacons and CoreLocation.  Everything so far works fine with every devices tried ( maybe 10-15 different models other than iPhone 7 ) and I register my 13 beacons no problem.  For some obscure reason my iPhone 7 won't take more than 10.  After that I get the :

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 5.)

If I remove a beacon that previously registered correctly, the 11th will register on the next startup.  If I put back the one I removed it won't register again.  So it really looks like the limit is 10... which is weird.  Prior to the latest iOS update, I got my phone to register all 13 but now it won't again.  I can't really say it's because of the update or because my phone restarted.  I'm trying to find another phone to reproduce the problem and I'll update the question if I do.  I tried the obvious: restarting, resetting, etc...

Thanks,
MAB

Comment: There is a device-wide limit to the number of beacon regions that can be registered. If other apps have already registered some beacon regions then the number your app can register is reduced. It is considered "nice" if an app uses a single uuid for all of its beacons, allowing a single region registration to cover all of that apps locations.

Comment: Thanks !! I'm not sure I understand completely tho. We are using a single UUID for all beacons in our app. Am I still limited by other apps installed ?

Comment: Yes, the number of beacon regions is a system-wide limit. If all of your beacons share a uuid then you only need a single beacon region (at least until you get the first region entry)

Comment: Thanks again, will be trying it tomorrow.  I'll post the results.

Comment: Acording to the Localisation Services screen, I've got only 1 app (mine) using geofencing.

Comment: Still no clue what's causing this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be 100% sure it never happens, on any phones, you need to wait for this delegate call before registering a beacon as documented :

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    // Now you can register you beacons if CLAuthorization is OK
}
```

May work without waiting, might as well not.  Fixed the problem for good.  You also get this error if you register beacons without the proper CLAuthorizationStatus.